# Masking Links in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm currently trying to mask a link within my rails application as it's linking out to different websites. I'll explain a simple scenario below:

Currently when hovering a link I get

http://www.testexampleoutsideurl.com/news/posts/1234

I'm trying to make it show

http://www.myapplication.com/offer/123

I'm using a basic rails scaffold set-up with friendly_id on my models. I've asked this before but it's giving me errors. Please see code below.

**The Error**

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column offers.friendly_id does not exist
>   LINE 1: SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE "offers"."friendly_id...
>   ^ : SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" WHERE "offers"."friendly_id" IS
>   NULL LIMIT 1

**offers_controller.rb**

```
# GET /offers/1.json
  def show
    link = Offer.find_by!(friendly_id: params[:slug])
    redirect_to link.url
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "offers/:slug", to: "offers#show"
```

**offer.rb**

```
class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
  validates :category, presence: true

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  mount_uploader :merchantImg, MerchantImgUploader
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

offers_controller.rb

```
  def show
    link = Offer.friendly.find(params[:slug])
    redirect_to link.url
  end
```

routes.rb

```
get "offers/:slug", to: "offers#show"
```

Console Error

> Couldn't find Offer without an ID

```
22:36:36 web.1    | [28829] 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Nov/2015:22:36:36 +0000] "GET /offers/blahihaidh HTTP/1.1" 404 118512 0.2532
```

Comment: Did you forget to run `rake db:migrate` after generating the scaffold, perhaps?

Comment: Yep - already ran. Works perfectly, except for this

Comment: The cause of the error, as @Macmee points out, is that your `offers` table doesn't have a `friendly_id` column. So either you don't have a migration that creates that column, or the migration hasn't been run. Can you edit your question to include your migration code?

Comment: @Jordan I've added the model - all migrations have been ran, also the migration within Macmee's answer

Comment: Why do you want to trick your users and mask the link? If you only want a nice hover-experience, just use the title attribute for your link tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the friendly_id gem. The [friendly_id README](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/8069fc9959215e5f4872927928b3b7a95e9beacd/README.md#rails-quickstart) has the following example:

```
User.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

...but your code looks like this:

```
link = Offer.find_by!(friendly_id: params[:slug])
```

Your code is failing because you're trying to use the ActiveRecord `find_by!` method, which takes as an argument a hash whose keys are expected to be column names, but your table doesn't have a `friendly_id` column. Instead, you should do as the friendly_id README indicates and use something like this:

```
link = Offer.friendly.find(params[:slug])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After implementing your answer I still get 'Couldn't find Offer without an ID' when trying to create an offer

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your updated code? Also can you include the relevant portion of the Rails log?

Comment: Can you post he relevant portion of the Rails log? It will start with "`Started GET "/offers/..." ...`" and end with "`Completed ...`" or an error message.

Comment: By default Rails in development mode generates a log that shows, among other things, every requests, which route it matches, what its parameters are, which controller action processes it, what database queries are executed, any exceptions that are raised, and what the returned status code is. It usually lives in `log/development.log`. This is the log I'm referring to.

Answer (score 2):

the error says:

`UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column offers.friendly_id does not exist`

so your table does not have a column called `friendly_id` and therefore the query is crashing.

Comment: But isn't it looking for the slug within the class?

Comment: did you run

rails generate migration AddFriendlyIdRef friendly_id:references and rake db:migrate?

Comment: also @Jonathan can you post your models?

Comment: Nope - I will add this now

Comment: Added Model to question